# c++ bind succeeds, lambda SEGV

Tags: c++, lambda, stdbind

Ok, please slap me upside the head.  What about lambda expressions am I not understanding?

Why does std::bind as in the comments below work fine, while the lamba expression evaporates and crashes at runtime?

How to make them stay for eggs and coffee in the morning?

```
    wrapper->setPoweredAttribute(true,  
         
        // using bind works fine
        //
        //std::bind(&BluetoothStateImpl::cb, this, std::placeholders::_1, evt.cb,  
        //    "BtOff_tryPowerOn", 
        //    [bst](){ bst->powerOn(); })); 
           
        // but below crashes on first line 
        //    
        [this,&evt,bst](connectivity::types::CommandResults x) 
        { 
            cb(x,evt.cb,"BtOff_tryPowerOn", // <-- SEGV here!!
                [bst](){ bst->powerOn(); }); 
        });
```

Comment: In the lambda version you are taking a reference to `evt` which is probably going out of scope. Take a copy of `evt.cb` instead.

Comment: ... where a capture to that effect would be `evt_cb = evt.cb`.

Comment: Thank you both, that worked!  @StoryTeller thank you for supporting Monica.  I´d like to give Milli Vanilli a second chance as well.